# How to build Dynamic Route using iron:router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

The following code is the usual way we can achieve to route.

```
Router.route('/', function(){
  this.render("", {to: 'content'});
});

Router.route('/user/add', function(){
   this.render("templateName", {to: 'content'});
});
```

Instead of the above i just try to construct the route map from the collection. For example:

```js
var allRoutes = [{
    "name" : "userDetail",
    "path" : "/user/add",
    "template" : [
        {
            "name" : "addUser",
            "section" : "content"
        }
    ],
    "options" : null
}, {
    "name" : "default",
    "path" : "/",
    "template" : [
        {
            "name" : "default",
            "section" : "content"
        }
    ],
    "options" : null
}];

for(var i=0;i<allRoutes.length;i++){
    Router.route(allRoutes[i].path, function(){
        var templates = allRoutes[i].template;
        for(var t=0;t<templates.length;t++){
            this.render(templates[t].name, {to:templates[t].section});
        }
    });
}
```

The way route maps are constructed that could see in browser console but it is not working when url take a place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use route options instead of functions http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-options; the function you are defining has undefined variables when it is called during run time (`allRoutes[i]` is only well defined during the execution of the for loop, not during execution of the route function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are defining has undefined variables when it is called during run time (`allRoutes[i]` is only well defined during the execution of the for loop, not during execution of the route function).

Use route options instead of functions http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-options:

```
for(var i=0;i<allRoutes.length;i++){
    var t = allRoutes[i].template[0];
    Router.route(allRoutes[i].path, {
        template: t.name;
        data: t.section);
        }
    });
}
```

BTW, you can't render more than one template per route.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Christian.

Comment: You're welcome. However, instead of saying thanks you should upvote and/or accept the answer. That's how stackoverflow works. Also, is there anything wrong with this answer or why did you post your own without any comment on what's better about it?

Comment: This is not the perfect solution what i asked for. May your code be a solution for accessing undefined values during the execution of the for loop. But i tried render more than one template to corresponding yield region from collections on every single route.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(var i=0;i<allRoutes.length;i++){
  Router.route(allRoutes[i].path, renderTemplate(allRoutes[i].template));
 }

// it renders the templates on router callback
function renderTemplate(templates){
  return function(){
    for(var t=0;t<templates.length;t++){
      this.render(templates[t].name, {to:templates[t].section});
     }
 }
}
```

This is the one way to do for multiple template rendering with corresponding "Yield" Section.It is working fine with temporary array in client but not with collections from MongoDB.